# How to gracefully shutdown (or put to sleep) a .Net Maui App

Tags: sleep, lifecycle, shutdown, maui

The web has many articles (and videos) on starting a new Maui app. Microsoft's Maui documentation does discuss the MauiApp lifecycle and enumerates delegates to trigger the appropriate events for each of the supported platforms. I have been unable to find any concrete example of how to initiate any of these events other than creation. Specifically, how do I initiate a MauiApp shutdown, whether that involves putting the app to sleep or actually removing it from memory, as appropriate for the platform? Maui metadata mentions such procedures as `Quit()`, `StopAsync()`, and `CloseWindow()` but I have been unable to get any of these (at least while debugging) to actually visibly terminate the app.

Comment: on iOS you don't do this, and on Android you shouldn't

Answer (score 21):

For Android apps:

```cs
Application.Current.Quit();
```

I tested it and it works.

It is compatible with other platforms, but I didn't test.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Windows.

Comment: And I can confirm this does nothing other than close the primary window that Quit was called from.
.NET Maui supports multiple windows, if any other windows are spawned, merely calling Quit will do nothing to end those. Additional windows must be handed first first before the application can be ended.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows desktop this works:

```
Application.Current?.CloseWindow(Application.Current.MainPage.Window);
```

Comment: I have tested! It works for Android too..

Answer (score 1):

Each of the given answers is incomplete.
.Net Maui supports multi windows on WinUI, Android, MacCatalyst, and possibly Tizen, but not iOS. Merely calling `Application.Current.Quit()` will do nothing more than close the Window of the instance it was called from.

To properly end an application you will need to first close any non primary windows spawned, and then `Quit` the primary or close its window.

Now it can be argued that this is a bug and calling Quit should end everything but at least currently it doesn't, so the given answers at least appear to be ignorant of this fact.